# Twitter Rate Limit json

Tags: twitter

I am still relatively new to Twitter development. so this is probably a stupid question. 
I am looking at a Twitter API library, and they have rate limit defined in the resource file

```
   <data name="QueryRateLimit" xml:space="preserve">
 <value>https://api.twitter.com/1.1/application/rate_limit_status.json</value>
```

what exactly does https://api.twitter.com/1.1/application/rate_limit_status.json do and what is it used for in the application?

Because if you just open a browser, and copy and past this link, you get authentication error, as expected. But if your request is authenticated, does that mean the json will return a certain set of values map to the rate limit of the session?

All tips and help are greatly appreciated.

Thanks

What

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/application/rate_limit_status) you will get something like this:

```
{
  "rate_limit_context": {
    "access_token": "119476949-oYGCs2M5duG5QalbOAK2YUZh8zG3ur7DPYo5qIFN"
  },
  "resources": {
    "help": {
      "/help/privacy": {
        "remaining": 15,
        "reset": 1346439527,
        "limit": 15
      },
      "/help/configuration": {
        "remaining": 15,
        "reset": 1346439527,
        "limit": 15
      },
      "/help/tos": {
        "remaining": 15,
        "reset": 1346439527,
        "limit": 15
      },
      "/help/languages": {
        "remaining": 15,
        "reset": 1346439527,
        "limit": 15
      }
    },
    "statuses": {
      "/statuses/oembed": {
        "remaining": 180,
        "reset": 1346439527,
        "limit": 180
      },
      "/statuses/user_timeline": {
        "remaining": 180,
        "reset": 1346439527,
        "limit": 180
      },
      "/statuses/mentions_timeline": {
        "remaining": 15,
        "reset": 1346439527,
        "limit": 15
      },
      "/statuses/home_timeline": {
        "remaining": 15,
        "reset": 1346439527,
        "limit": 15
      },
      "/statuses/show/:id": {
        "remaining": 180,
        "reset": 1346439527,
        "limit": 180
      },
      "/statuses/retweets/:id": {
        "remaining": 15,
        "reset": 1346439527,
        "limit": 15
      }
    },
    "users": {
      "/users/show": {
        "remaining": 180,
        "reset": 1346439527,
        "limit": 180
      },
      "/users/search": {
        "remaining": 180,
        "reset": 1346439527,
        "limit": 180
      },
      "/users/suggestions": {
        "remaining": 15,
        "reset": 1346439527,
        "limit": 15
      },
      "/users/contributors": {
        "remaining": 15,
        "reset": 1346439527,
        "limit": 15
      },
      "/users/suggestions/:slug/members": {
        "remaining": 15,
        "reset": 1346439527,
        "limit": 15
      },
      "/users/suggestions/:slug": {
        "remaining": 15,
        "reset": 1346439527,
        "limit": 15
      },
      "/users/contributees": {
        "remaining": 15,
        "reset": 1346439527,
        "limit": 15
      },
      "/users/lookup": {
        "remaining": 180,
        "reset": 1346439527,
        "limit": 180
      }
    },
    "search": {
      "/search/tweets": {
        "remaining": 180,
        "reset": 1346439527,
        "limit": 180
      }
    }
  }
}
```